# render text as component reactJS

Tags: reactjs, latex, render

I'm creating a platform for math exchanges with reactJS and i wish that users can write latex codes so i found react-latex and it works fine but when i store a paragraph in database with some latex inside so when i store in database i use  like i use it with react-latex but when i render what i get from database i get only what is inside  and  because it is not a html code.

My question is how can i render that part of code as a react component ?

Best,

Comment: Dangerously Set innerHTML     https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: hi, my problem is not with the HTML but with the component <Latex> what i want to use as react component not as HTML.

Comment: Can you post working example with the problem?